# How to generate a texture for UV Mapping of a tapered cylinder?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a real object like a Starbucks cup and designed it in Blender. Now I want the texture for the UV Mapping. I took 20 photos around the object and added it in photoshop. My first intention was to create a panorama. This was wrong. It looked so horrible (the quality of my photos was perfekt).

Has anybody an idea, how I can create my texture of this tapered cylinder?

Comment: moonboooooooots!!!! you are late....!!!!

Comment: @Chris desertboooooots!!! and now....????

Comment: ;) moonboots is a very talented young (*cough*) guy here who is very good with UV Mapping...so i thought he would see this and answer this in 10 secs ;) well, i am not an UV expert, but if you provide a blend file i would take a look....

Comment: i don't know how good you are with UV Editing....but you can always use "project from view" and then Blender just puts that image just on your object from that view from which you are looking at it: result like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7yI9.jpg -> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0UMz.gif

Comment: @Chris aaaah :D I though it's an english proverb for something but I dind't find anything in google.

It's a good idea but with my 20 photos not possible to get them exactly in position